# Knockout not saving/detects changes

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

html

```
       <div class="infoview-details" data-bind="foreach: Container"> 
            @* <span data-bind="text: sub().sub_name" ></span>*@
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                    <span data-bind="visible: sub().interval_from"><input type="text" data-bind="value: sub().interval_from" /></span>
                    <span data-bind="text: sub().limitTypeSymbol" ></span>
                    <span data-bind="visible: sub().interval_to"><input type="text" data-bind="value: sub().interval_to" /></span>
                    <span data-bind="visible: sub().value"><input type="text" data-bind="value: sub().value" /></span>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary"data-bind="click: $parent.loadNewTestValidation">Update</a>
                </div>
            </div>




            <hr />             
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary"data-bind="click: saveValidation">Save</a>
```

ViewModel

```
function baseAppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Container= ko.observableArray([]); 

    self.saveValidation = function (data) {

        app.ajax.post({
            url: app.url() + 'api/base/save/' +       self.id(),
            data: ko.toJS(data.Container),
            done: function () {
                self.load(self.id());

            }

        });
    };
```

Model 1

```
function Container(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.sub= ko.observable(new sub(data.sub));       
}
```

Model 2

```
function sub(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.type_output_id = ko.observable(data.type_output_id);
    self.output_type_id = ko.observable(data.output_type_id);
    self.validation_name = ko.observable(data.validation_name);
    self.limit_type = ko.observable(data.limit_type);
    self.value = ko.observable(data.value);
    self.interval_from = ko.observable(data.interval_from);
    self.interval_to = ko.observable(data.interval_to);    
}
```

When I change and update I get the new values from input, but if add new values and saves I don't.
When I save I don't even get the data in the xhr request that is send to knockout.
So something MUST be wrong in the html code, but I don't have an idea. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please add more context to the question and be specific about where there error is occuring or expected behaviour fails. Otherwise we will have to trawl through your code to find issues. Create a working JSFiddle if you can.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer was:**

```
        <div data-bind="with:Container">

            <input class="btn-save float-r" type="submit" data-bind="click: $parent.saveValidation" />
        </div>
```

Then the new changes was detect.